# Wrong calculation for daily partitions

Tags: oracle

Oracle : 11.2.0.2
I'm trying to drop monthy and daily partitions using a script. This works fine for monthly partitions but not for daily partitions. Below is the error I see in the log. Day of the month is becoming zero when calculating.

```
2013-08-0|SYS_P328538|2|YES
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month
ORA-06512: at line 43
```

Here below is the script. I think highvalue date is miscalculated.

```
SQL> DECLARE
2      CURSOR tab_part_cur IS
3          select PARTITION_POSITION, PARTITION_NAME,HIGH_VALUE,INTERVAL from dba_tab_partitions where table_name = 'MO_USAGEDATA' 
and table_owner = 'WSMUSER17' 
order by  PARTITION_POSITION;
4      tab_part_rec tab_part_cur%ROWTYPE;
5      lHighValue LONG;
6      strPartitionLessThanDate VARCHAR2(100);
7      dtTestDate DATE;
8      DaysInPast NUMBER;
9      SQLstr varchar2(100);
10      strIntervalType varchar2(1000);
11      strRunType varchar2(20);
12  BEGIN
13      strRunType := 'DRY_RUN';
14      select INTERVAL into strIntervalType from dba_part_tables where table_name ='MO_USAGEDATA' and owner = 'WSMUSER17';
15      strIntervalType := REGEXP_SUBSTR(strIntervalType, '''[^'']+''');
16      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(strIntervalType);
17          CASE
18          WHEN strIntervalType = '''DAY''' THEN
19              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Interval type = '||strIntervalType);
20  --            dtTestDate := CURRENT_DATE - 7 - 1;  Offset adjustment if necessary
21              dtTestDate := CURRENT_DATE - 7;
22              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Test Date = '||dtTestDate);
23          WHEN strIntervalType = '''MONTH''' THEN
24              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Interval type = '||strIntervalType);
25  --              dtTestDate := CURRENT_DATE - 90;
26                  dtTestDate := ADD_MONTHS(current_date,- 7);
27              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TestDate = '||dtTestDate);
28          ELSE
29              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Unexpected interval, exiting.');
30              GOTO EXIT;
31      END CASE;
32      OPEN tab_part_cur;
33      LOOP
34          FETCH tab_part_cur INTO tab_part_rec;
35          EXIT WHEN tab_part_cur%NOTFOUND;
36          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(tab_part_cur%ROWCOUNT);
37          lHighValue := tab_part_rec.high_value;
38          /* This next line seems redundant but is needed for conversion quirk from LONG to  VARCHAR2
39           */
40          strPartitionLessThanDate := lHighValue;
41          strPartitionLessThanDate := substr(strPartitionLessThanDate, 11, 10);
42 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(strPartitionLessThanDate ||'|'|| tab_part_rec.partition_name  ||'|'||  tab_part_rec.partition_position ||'|'|| tab_part_rec.interval);
43  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_DATE(strPartitionLessThanDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') ||'******'||dtTestDate);
44 IF TO_DATE(strPartitionLessThanDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') < dtTestDate AND  tab_part_rec.partition_name <> 'PART_MINVALUE
' THEN
45  SQLstr := 'ALTER TABLE WSMUSER17.MO_USAGEDATA DROP PARTITION '||tab_part_rec.partition_name  ||' update Global indexes';
46              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Targeted Partition !!!!!!!!');
47              IF strRunType = 'LIVE_RUN' THEN
48                  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Dropping Partition !!!!!!!!');
49                execute immediate SQLstr;
50              END IF;
51          END IF;
52      END LOOP;
53      CLOSE tab_part_cur;
54      << EXIT >>
55     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Partition purge complete');
56  END;
57  /
'DAY'
Interval type = 'DAY'
Test Date = 03-SEP-13
1
2012-06-1|PART_MINVALUE|1|NO
01-JUN-12******03-SEP-13
2
2013-08-0|SYS_P328538|2|YES
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month
ORA-06512: at line 43
```

I'm trying to keep lat 7 partitions in the daily partitioned table and drop the rest of the partitions. But its not dropping them.

Comment: I can't reproduce, can you post the **minimum** `CREATE table` statement that produces this behaviour. minimum=at most one column, two partitions

Comment: CREATE TABLE "TEST"."MO_USAGEDATA"
   (    "USAGEDATAID" NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
        "REQUSERNAME" VARCHAR2(128 CHAR),
        "REQUESTDTS" TIMESTAMP (9) NOT NULL ENABLE,
        "REQUESTMILLIS" NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
        "CUSTOMFIELD1" VARCHAR2(256 CHAR),
        "NMREQMSGSIZE" NUMBER(38,0),
        "NMRESPMSGSIZE" NUMBER(38,0),
        "OTHERUSERNAMES" VARCHAR2(512 CHAR))
 partition by range ("REQUESTDTS")
        INTERVAL(NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,'DAY'))
 (partition PART_MINVALUE values less than (TIMESTAMP '2012-06-18 00:00:00'))
  TABLESPACE "TEST1";

Comment: I had to remove some columns because of the space constraint, but the partitioned column, requestdts is there.

Comment: What do `lHighValue` and/or `strPartitionLessThanDate ` have before you apply the `substr`? If you `set serveroutput on format wrapped` do you see a leading space before the partial date? It looks like the `substr` is just one character out, but it's not obvious why. It might be safer to use `high value_length` to get the last 10 chars, rather than always starting at the same point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I created the table, inserted some data and ran some of your queries and you've got something wrong with your substring:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE "MO_USAGEDATA" (
  2  "REQUESTDTS" TIMESTAMP (9) NOT NULL ENABLE
  3  )
  4  partition by range ("REQUESTDTS") INTERVAL(NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,'DAY'))
  5  (partition PART_MINVALUE values less than(TIMESTAMP '2012-06-18 00:00:00'));

Table created

SQL> INSERT INTO MO_USAGEDATA 
  2     (SELECT SYSDATE + ROWNUM FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 30);

30 rows inserted

SQL> SELECT high_value, INTERVAL
  2    FROM all_tab_partitions
  3   WHERE table_name = 'MO_USAGEDATA'
  4     AND table_owner = USER
  5   ORDER BY PARTITION_POSITION;

HIGH_VALUE                           INTERVAL
------------------------------------ ---------
[...]
TIMESTAMP' 2013-09-30 00:00:00'      YES
TIMESTAMP' 2013-10-01 00:00:00'      YES
TIMESTAMP' 2013-10-02 00:00:00'      YES
[...]

SQL> SELECT substr('TIMESTAMP'' 2013-10-02 00:00:00''', 11, 10) FROM dual;

SUBSTR('TIMESTAMP''2013-10-020
------------------------------
 2013-10-0
```

As you can see you're off by one character. It works with `DATE` columns, but for `TIMESTAMP` partitionning, you'll need to adjust the offset.